# Updating Ruby on Rails "created_at" date with Perl

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, perl

I'm using Perl to populate a database that will be displayed via Ruby on Rails.  The database was created via a Rails migration.

I have a date string formatted in Perl to fit the Rails "created_at" date convention but MySQL isn't allowing it.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

```
($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst)=localtime(time);
$rails_time = printf ("%4d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d",$year+1900,$mon+1,$mday,$hour,$min,$sec);
print "$rails_time\n";
```

Comment: The formatted string seems to be valid MySQL datetime syntax. Could you post the bit of Perl code where you're trying to populate the database?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Remember to up vote all helpful answers, including those to others' questions. Remember to "check" / approve the best answer to your own questions.

Comment: my $sth = $dbh_new->prepare("INSERT INTO trends SET title='$read_names[$n]', url='$read_urls[$n]', created_at='$rails_time'");

Answer (score 4):

Perl's [`printf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html) doesn't return the formatted string:

> Equivalent to `print FILEHANDLE sprintf(FORMAT, LIST)`, except that `$\` (the output record separator) is not appended.

So your `$rails_time` ends up being what [`print`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) returns (most likely `1`). You want to use [`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) to produce your ISO-8601-ish timestamp:

```
$rails_time = sprintf("%4d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", $year + 1900, $mon + 1, $mday, $hour, $min, $sec);
```

MySQL will happily accept that `$rails_time` as a timestamp value.

Answer (score 1):

Much easier with [`Time::Piece`](http://p3rl.org/Time%3a%3aPiece) (distributed with Perl):

```
use Time::Piece qw(localtime);
localtime->strftime('%F %T');
# returns string '2012-04-24 12:11:31'
```

Comment: Also gave me what I wanted, but I'm going with the other answer because I want to limit the amount of modules I'm using.